# Inputs for searching (form:select)

Tags: input

Is it possible to use `<a href="data/searchby/{name}">Search</a>` like this in order to refer a specific {name} provided by an input? I want to create an input form like: `<form:select items="${cars}" path="car" itemLabel="type" itemValue="id"/>`. This is my controller mapping:     `@GetMapping("/searchby/{name}")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible but not recommended, from what i know using url parameters (domain.com/page?value=theValue) is better

Comment: How to create an input that refers to my mapping? @GetMapping("/searchby/{name}")

Comment: @Bono.str after a google search i asume your using java springboot, im not familiar with it try searching google how to make url parameters in google